# how to generate wsdl with SvcUtil?

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

Is it possible to generate wsdl with use of SvcUtil or any other tool. I know I can view wsdl in browser while running the service but I need to have one wsdl file that doesn't have xsd:import directive but rather specifies all the information in this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a one off you could manually construct the single WSDL file.  But that's no fun.  :)

Another way is to create an endpoint behavior.  See [Improving WCF Interoperability: Flattening your WSDL](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html) for the full details.